# Ошибка при POST запросе используя OKHTTP

Tags: java, android, okhttp

Пытаюсь отправить обычный post запрос на свой сайт, используя библиотеку okhttp.

```
public void onMyButtonClick(View view)
{
    //String myURL = "http://s92640jz.bget.ru/register.php";
    //String parammetrs = "login=22&open_key=XXX&key_size=4096";

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("login", "22")
            .add("open_key", "XXX")
            .add("key_size", "4096")
            .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://s92640jz.bget.ru/register.php")
            .post(formBody)
            .build();

    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        //выведет ответ сервера
        //Log.i("LOG", response.body().string());
        // Do something with the response.
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

На строчке

```
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Происходит краш со следующей ошибкой:

```
07-10 19:16:33.272 7636-7636/com.example.jack.myapplication5 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204) 
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355) 
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
       at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
       at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
       at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:172)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:138)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:80)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:178)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:129)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:98)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
       at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:109)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:124)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:170)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:60)
       at com.example.jack.myapplication5.MainActivity.onMyButtonClick(MainActivity.java:51)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204) 
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355) 
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

В манифесте доступ к интернету добавил. Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По умолчанию OkHttp выполняет запрос в том потоке, откуда вызвано. В вашем случае это основной, UI поток. А в нём нельзя ходить в сеть с API>=14, о чём и говорит вам ваша ошибка `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Решить это можно средствами самой либы, вызвав метод `enqueue` c колбэком, куда придёт ответ, [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34967554/3212712):

```
client.newCall(request)
        .enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(final Call call, IOException e) {
                // Error
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // For the example, you can show an error dialog or a toast
                        // on the main UI thread
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                String res = response.body().string();
                Log.d("TAG", "response is: "+res);
                // Do something with the response
            }
        });
```

Или запустив код из вашего вопроса вне UI потока. Через AsyncTask, создание нового Thread, в IntentService или ещё как-нибудь.